# django Url endswith regex in url path

Tags: python, regex, django, url, django-views

I need to support following urls in single url regex.

```
/hotel_lists/view/
/photo_lists/view/
/review_lists/view/
```

how to support all above urls in single views?

I tried something like below

```
url(r'^\_lists$/(?P<resource>.*)/$', 'admin.views.customlist_handler'),
```

edit:
hotel,photo, review is just example. that first part will be dynamic. first part can be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to capture the resource type in the view, you could do this:

```
url(r'^(?P<resource>hotel|photo|review)_lists/view/$', 'admin.views.customlist_handler'),
```

Or to make it more generic,

```
url(r'^(?P<resource>[a-z]+)_lists/view/$', 'admin.views.customlist_handler'), #Or whatever regex pattern is more appropriate
```

and in the view

```
def customlist_handler(request, resource):
    #You have access to the resource type specified in the URL.
    ...
```

You can read more on [named URL pattern groups here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#named-groups)

Comment: first part of url , hotel, review, photo is just example. some other resource will also be start with. can you suggest how to do?

Comment: Check the edit.. The second URL pattern in the answer addresses exactly that. Note that I am assuming that the resource has only lowercase alphabets. You can modify the regex pattern to accommodate your usecase. .