# django 2.2.5 URL regex in url path

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I would like to support the above views in a single view in url ...in my search I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086369/django-url-endswith-regex-in-url-path) which is no longer supported and all the tutorials i've found have been outdated, which demonstrate how to accomplish the task in django 1.8.3.

In 'products/views.py' I have created a views for products and details. ProductListView will display all products, while ProductDetailView will display a single product detail (title, description, price etc).

products/views.py

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = "products/list.html"


class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = "products/detail.html"
```

products/urls.py include path to the views for ProductListView and ProductDetailView. ProductListView appears to be correct. ProductDetailView is incorrect! I'm getting the following warnings:

> WARNINGS: ?: (2_0.W001) Your URL pattern '^products/(?P\d+)/$'
>   [name='details'] has a route that contains '(?P<', begins with a '^',
>   or ends with a '$'. This was likely an oversight when migrating to
>   django.urls.path().

ecommerce.py/urls.py is where i've included products and details urls

ecommerce/urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from .views import home, about, contact

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('about/', about, name='about'),
    path('products/', include('products.urls'), name='products'),
    path('products/', include('products.urls'), name='details'),
    path('contact/', contact, name='contact'),
    path('account/', include('allauth.urls'), name='login'),
    path('register/', include('allauth.urls'), name='register'),

              ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)



products/urls.py

    from django.urls import path
    from .import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='products'),
        path(r'^products/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='details')
    ]
```

Comment: If you want to use regex to match your urls then try to use `re_path` instead. Or with path, you should change to `path('product/<int:id>/', ...)`.

Comment: re_path(r'^products/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ProductDetailView.as_view()) is working, but is there a cleaner more efficient way of doing this?     path('products/<int:id>', ProductDetailView.as_view()) is not working.

Comment: I believe this `path('products/<int:pk>/', ProductDetailView.as_view())` should work the same as `re_path(r'^products/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ProductDetailView.as_view())`. Change `id` to `pk` might work.

Comment: Thanks. path('products/<int:pk>/', ProductDetailView.as_view()) works. Why didn't path('products/<int:id>/', ProductDetailView.as_view()) work? Isn't pk == id?

Comment: Let me give you a detail answer so that you can see why that happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got that warning because Django unable to match the url to any of your `urlpattern`. Shortly you can use this to solve your problem:

```
# products/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='products'),
    path('products/<int:pk>/$', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='details')
]
```

or if you want to use regex to match your url then:

```
# products/urls.py

from django.urls import path, re_path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='products'),
    re_path(r'^products/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='details')
]
```

The reason is because your `ProductDetailView` are inheriting from `DetailView` of Django. That View already implemented some mixin to get the object from `pk` key instead of `id` that's why when you change to use `<int:pk>` it'll works.

You can take a look at [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b1d6b35e146aea83b171c1b921178bbaae2795ed/django/views/generic/detail.py#L103) to see how Django implementing to query the object. (Keep you eyes on `SingleObjectMixin` mixin and property `pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'`.

I also recommend you to change the value of `pk_url_kwarg` in `ProductDetailView` view and also remember to change `pk` in the urlpattern into the new value which match with `pk_url_kwarg` value.